# Allow a worker thread to work while the main thread is showing a dialog

Tags: c#, multithreading, forms

I want show a form as a dialog but problem is that the worker thread has stopped working and is now waiting for the main thread that is showing the dialog.

The worker thread should not wait and should start working in background. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Does your worker thread use an `Invoke` command to update GUI controls on the main thread?  Invoke waits until the command has completed, but it can't because the main thread is blocked by the dialog.  Try using `BeginInvoke` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't said what your worker thread is doing. Assuming you're already using a background thread, my guess is that you're using `Control.Invoke` or `Dispatcher.Invoke`, which are blocking calls, in order to communicate with the UI.

If you use `Control.BeginInvoke` or `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` instead, you won't be blocked. Those calls just post a message to the UI thread without waiting for it to be processed.

Of course, there may be something else going on - giving us more information would really help.

Answer (score 5):

Try to use a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx), which will do your work in a separate thread rather than the main thread.

Check this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to see how to work with a background worker.